# Generate dynamic URLs with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a simple flask page that displays links from a dictionary of text/links:

```
urls = {'look at this page': www.example.com, 'another_page': www.example2.com}   

@app.route('/my_page')
def index(urls=urls):
    return render_template('my_page.html',urls=urls)
```

My template page looks like this:

```
{%- block content %}
{%- for url in urls %}
    <a href="{{ url_for(urls.get(url)) }}">{{ url }}</a>
{%- endfor %}
{%- endblock content %}
```

I can't quite seem to understand how to create dynamic urls like this. The code produces this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can anyone point out my problem or a solution?

UPDATE: Here's my updated code:

```
  @app.route('/my_page')
    def index():
        context = {'urls': urls}
        return render_template('index.html', context=context)
```

And the template:

```
{%- block content %}
    {% for key, data in context.items() %}
        {% for text, url in data.items() %}
            <a href="{{ url }}">{{ text }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock content %}
```

This solution is close, however each link get prepended with my app's url. In other words I get this:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.example.com">look at this page</a>
```

I just want:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">look at this page</a>
```

Comment: Do you know what `url_for` is for? It takes a so called endpoint as first parameter. Do you just want a list of links? Also, what is `urls` exactly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd just like to build a series of links from a dictionary of urls where the key is the text and value is the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
urls = {
    'A search engine.': 'http://google.com',
    'Great support site': 'http://stackoverflow.com'
}

@app.route('/my_page')
def index(): # why was there urls=urls here before?
    return render_template('my_page.html',urls=urls)
```

---

```
{%- block content %}
{%- for text, url in urls.iteritems() %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ text }}</a>
{%- endfor %}
{%- endblock content %}
```

`url_for` is only for building URLs with Flask. Like in your case:

```
print url_for('index') # will print '/my_page' ... just a string, no magic here
```

`url_for` takes an endpoint name as first parameter which is by default the name of the view function. So the endpoint name for your view function `index()` is simply `'index'`.